# Restoring Aptik Data

Tags: backup

I'm using `aptik-gtk` to atttempt to restore files to my computer from my external hard drive. I made sure to backup every checkbox from the previous system. The thing is that on the new OS, aptik is saying this when trying to restore just the home data directory (Text is not copy-able)[image: Terminal Result]

There isn't a folder called `Aptik Backup/Scripts/files` (The scripts folder is empty aside for a readme), but there is an archive called `Aptik Backup/home/files/sarah/data.tar.temp` I believe that this contains the home folder data (Its over 190GB). How can I restore my Home Data?

Here is a tree of the Aptik Backup folder
[image: Tree]

Comment: IMHO it's unfortunate that a major change was made to Aptik right at this Bionic transition.  The old version was rock solid and reliable, the new version hasn't been too stable in my experience.  Have you tried simply unzipping the `data.tar.gz.temp` file to see if your data is there?

Comment: @OrganicMarble That's what I'm doing now (Started at post), but at 190GB, it'll be awhile...

Comment: I was able to restore the data by extraction of the archive home/files/sarah/data.tar.gz.temp

Comment: Good news! Glad you got your data.